# Golang namespaces of namespaces

Tags: go, package

I'm kinda new to go and from being a C++ background I really wonder if its possible to achieve something like this. Let's say I have a math library and i want to make a namespace a children of another namespace like this.

- main package
- math package

  - matrix package
  - ...

And I want to call my code like this ;

```
math.matrix.CreateTranslation(mat4, 30, 50, 0)
```

Is there a way to achieve this kind of behaviour in go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this kind of behaviour in go?

No, not really.

You can import `"module/math"` and then do `math.SomeFunc`. Or you can import `"module/math/matrix"` and then do `matrix.SomeOtherFunc`. These are referred to as "qualified identifiers".

But you cannot import `"module/math"` or `"module/math/matrix"` and then use a *nested* "qualified identifier" a la `math.matrix.SomeOtherFunc`. It's just not part of the [spec](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Qualified_identifiers).

---

Technically speaking it is possible to do the following:

```golang
math.Matrix.CreateTranslation(mat4, 30, 50, 0)
```

where `Matrix` is an exported *variable* in the `math` package and whose type either has a `CreateTranslation` method in its method set, or whose type is a *struct* type that has a function *field* called `CreateTranslation`.

While possible, it would, obviously, be an attempt to force an organizational pattern on a language that does not support it.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, after your second answer it made it a lot clear. I guess I'll follow the language standard and not do something like that.